# Setting base names based on request headers in ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, localization, internationalization

I have a spring boot application which has the following messages outside the jar/war

```
/i18n/myApplication/messages/companyA/messages.properties
/i18n/myApplication/messages/companyA/messages_fr_FR.properties
/i18n/myApplication/messages/companyB/messages.properties
/i18n/myApplication/messages/companyB/messages_fr_FR.properties
/i18n/myApplication/messages/companyB/messages_zh_HK.properties
```

In request header I would get the following

```
X-Company=CompanyA
Accept-Language=fr-FR
```

How do I set baseNames dynamically based on the company and locale?

Also for CompanyA I do not want to look for messages in CompanyB for Eg:
if

```
X-Company=CompanyA
Accept-Language=zh-HK
```

I should be able to default to en-IN properties.

Any new company that gets added I don't want to make any code changes to support it

I was thinking of extending ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Answer (score 0):

In order for our application to be able to determine which locale is currently being used, we need to add a LocaleResolverbean:

`
@Bean

public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();

slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);

return slr;

}
`

The LocaleResolver interface has implementations that determine the current locale based on the session, cookies, the Accept-Language header, or a fixed value.

Next, we need to add an interceptor bean that will switch to a new locale based on the value of the lang parameter appended to a request:

`
@Bean

public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {

LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();

lci.setParamName("lang");

return lci;

}
`

In order to take effect, this bean needs to be added to the application’s interceptor registry.
To achieve this, our @Configuration class has to implement the WebMvcConfigurer interface and override the addInterceptors() method:

`
@Override

public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());

}
`

It you read the documentation giù will find the simplest example Accept-language header which perfectly fits your needs